# Explain against - meaning

Tags: meaning

What does ***explain against*** mean ?

There you have an example

> He makes the subject more interesting by explaining against the
> background of his own narrative.

Provide more examples, definitions/meanings and so on.

Comment: You're parsing it slightly wrong.  "Explain against" isn't one phrase.  He is explaining.  How is he doing it?  Against the background of his own narrative.  Try looking up the meaning of "against the background" (or "against the backdrop").

Comment: What is the source of this quote, please?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting example. We would need more context to be sure what happened to lead up to this but a likely scenario is that the speaker has just outlined his own narrative as a background and he uses that narrative in as a background to his explanation. The key phrase here is *against the background* which you would use when describing a scene. So you might say that the white flowers were perfectly set off against the grey background.